# Prove Differentiation Multivariable

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given $f(x,y) = \frac{ xy^2}{x^2 +y^2}$

From defintion we know it is differentiable if:
$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F(X+h)-F(X)-c*h}{|h|}$ exists, where $c$ is the gradient of the function.

I have calculated the gradient. I am stuck at to how to prove that the given limit exists.

Is the following correct:

If I have to prove differntiablity at $(a,a)$

$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{F((x+h),(a))-F(x,a)-c*h}{|h|}$  That is take $y$ as constant, and show that the x limit exists and then do vice versa.

Is this the correct way of trying to do this? If not can you direct me?

Comment: "I know this function to be differntiable (...). I want to learn the process of how to prove that such a function is differentiable. I can prove not differentiable." Don't you think this is a little bit confusing for the reader?

"I don't think the actual numbers are too important, since this is a homework question." It would help to know, no?

If you are looking for a general algorithm/method to check if a function if differentiable or not, it does not exist.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. Since this is a homework question we are told that it is differentiable. F(x) = xy^2/(x^2+y^2)